# How do I turn off push notifications without turning off notifications in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, notifications, skype

I want to turn off push notifications for a single app (Skype, in this case) because I accidentally said "Yes" when it prompted me to receive push notifications.

I do not want to turn off notifications.  When I have Skype open, I want to receive notifications.  When Skype is closed, I do not want to receive notifications.  My understanding is that push notifications are the type that come when the app is closed.

How can I do this?

**Update - clarification**

I want to receive notifications from Skype, but only when Skype is running.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > Notifications. Scroll down until you find Skype and tap on it. Then you'll be able to set the notification settings for that app without turning notifications off entirely.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question.  I do not want to turn off notifications for Skype.  I want to turn off _push_ notifications for Skype.  Under Settings->Notifications I do not see a way to distinguish between the two.

Comment: What's the difference between push notifications and just notifications? Skype only sends push notifications, right?

Comment: Good question.  Push notifications are sent when the application is closed.  If the application is open, it's not a push notification... I guess.  What I know is that after I answered "yes" to the question "Allow Skype to send push notifications?" I started to receive notifications when Skype was closed.  Before that, I only received notifications when Skype was open.  My understanding of "push" is that the application doesn't need to be open or have a connection to a server.  I understand that push really means server initiated.  But that doesn't seem to be a sufficient definition here.

Comment: Push notifications are sent "through a constantly open IP connection to forward notifications from the servers of third party applications to the Apple devices" [Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Push_Notification_Service). So, push notifications require Internet and a server behind it.

Comment: Since the only notifications you'll be getting from Skype *are* from a server, this doesn't really matter. However, if Skype were to send local notifications (not from an APN server), this would be a problem. Basically, my solution should solve your **exact** need, but does not solve your need in a broad sense.

Comment: My need is to stop notifications when Skype is not running.

Comment: What I outlined above should work.

Answer (score -2):

I found the answer here: [How to turn off push notifications](http://www.push-notifications.com/how-to-turn-off-push-notifications/)

Comment: Answers on ask difference need to be more than just a link. The goal is for them to stand on their own, in case the link someday points to a site that no longer works.

Comment: Answers that are just a link are discouraged because a link may disappear leaving oj long term value for users who may later read your answer.